# Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context when += to UILabel.text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to add the string "7" to a label when someone tabs the button labeled 7.

But when using += "7", it gives me the error "Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context", when using the operator = "7" it works fine. Why doesn't += "7" work?

```
class NumberPadController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!

    /// set value in main vc and return to that.
    @IBAction func doneEntering(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let valueString = valueLabel.text, let valueDouble = Double(valueString), let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController as? ViewController else {
            // FIXME: Show error
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        presentingVC.valuePassedFromNumPad = valueDouble
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func seven(_ sender: Any) {
        valueLabel.text += "7" // Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context
        valueLabel.text = "a" // works fine
    }
}
```

Comment: what the OP you expect , you want to perform some operation or else

Comment: You just need to unwrap the optional value before adding up. Just make sure `UILabel` `text` property it is not nil before incrementing its value:

`valueLabel.text! += "7"`

Comment: It is worth saying that you should not use the UI to pass values around. If you need the label string value for future use you should keep a reference to its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text` property is *optional*.  One way to do this safely would be to use `append` along with *optional chaining*:

```
valueLabel.text?.append("7")
```

or use `+=` with *optional chaining*:

```
valueLabel.text? += "7"
```

If the label is `nil`, these would safely do nothing.  If you'd like the label to be `"7"` if it was `nil`, then use [@RickyMo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55056696/1630618).

Comment: How can I calculate my foodPrice label value with foodQuantity value? `var quantity = 1` and `foodPrice.text *= quantity`. I am getting same error

Comment: @EmreDeğirmenci, you need to take the `String` that is in `foodPrice.text`, convert it to a `Double`, multiply that by `Double(quantity)`, then convert that `Double` back to a `String`.  Something like `let price = Double(foodPrice.text ?? "") ?? 0; let total = price * Double(quantity); foodPrice.text = "\(total)"`

Answer (score 4):

`text` property is optional. To do it safely :

```
valueLabel.text =  (valueLabel.text ?? "") + "7"
```